# Can I integrate Music Keys in Javascript

Tags: javascript, key-events

I think the answer is no, but I'd still like to make sure. I'm trying to integrate the mediaplayer keys (on the keyboard) to a javascript function somehow. As a roundabout way, I've found the [Ubuntu Webapps Integration](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/ubuntu-12.04/javascript/index.html), but that would only function in Ubuntu 12.10. Is there a similar solution available for Windows, or is it impossible to do without a custom plugin?

I have also tried the [JS KeyTest](http://unixpapa.com/js/testkey.html) and it does not return me any keycodes for music keys.

Comment: No, if your os+browser does not fire key events for them, you can hardly use them.

Comment: Is there any API in Windows similar to the Ubuntu WebApps integration?

Comment: So you don't want a web page, but a windows desktop widget?

Answer (score 1):

I have just tested on Windows 7 with FF 7 with my IBM Keyboard and it returns the following for `Stop`,`Play/Pause`,`Back`, `Forward`:

```
keydown  keyCode=178       which=178       charCode=0        
keypress keyCode=178       which=0         charCode=0        
keyup    keyCode=178       which=178       charCode=0        
keydown  keyCode=179       which=179       charCode=0        
keypress keyCode=179       which=0         charCode=0        
keyup    keyCode=179       which=179       charCode=0        
keydown  keyCode=177       which=177       charCode=0        
keypress keyCode=177       which=0         charCode=0        
keyup    keyCode=177       which=177       charCode=0        
keydown  keyCode=176       which=176       charCode=0        
keypress keyCode=176       which=0         charCode=0        
keyup    keyCode=176       which=176       charCode=0
```